# Add UILabel to a specific indexpath in UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

Here is my code

```c
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10;
}

- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"dfdsfs" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.item == 0) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
        label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"this is item %ld", (long)indexPath.item];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        NSLog(@"im @ zero");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"im here %ld", (long)indexPath.item);
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

I want label to be added at index path zero only.
I'm getting issue as the label appears in other index paths also..

Answer (score 0):

In your case, inside the if condition, you can also add:

```
label.tag = 1000; // or other number
```

And, inside else add:

```
[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000].hidden = YES;
```

The problem was that the cell at indexPath.item == 0 may get reused for the other index paths, and it is still visible.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @SunilKumar You're welcome! Did it work? If yes - please accept my answer.